# Create groups of functions with same name within single module without classes

Tags: functional-programming, python-3.6

I am writing a card game simulator. During play, I want different players to have different strategies. My idea is to have 2 functions specified for a given agent than can be imported. These functions would have the same signatures. I know how to do this with classes and inheritance, but I'm trying to code this project entirely functionally. Here is what I have if I were to do it with classes:

```
class Agent:
  def __init__(self,position):
    self.pos = position

  def flip_two(self,gs):
    pass

  def regular_move(self,gs):
    pass

class Random_Agent(Agent):
  def flip_two(self,gs):
    #some code that alters gs randomly

  def regular_move(self,gs):
    #some code that alters gs randomly

class etc_Agents(Agent):
  .
  .
  .
```

The best answer I can think of so far is to put each agent in a new file, since modules would be a way to group the functions.

Thanks for any insight!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you wish to group related functions, you could place them in a dictionary like so:

```
options = {
    'a' : {'sameName' : lambda x: x*2},
    'b' : {'sameName' : lambda x: x**2}
    }
print(options['a']['sameName'](5))
print(options['b']['sameName'](5))
```